# Remove reference object from table - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ckreference

I am having issues to remove a reference relationship from a table.

I have the following `user2reference` added to the following table.

[image]

And I want just to remove this reference relationship from the table. It should look like this:

[image]

Tried to store an empty string or an `CKReference` with an empty recordName but **does not work**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
database.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: "user2reference"))
    {
        record, error in
        if let record = record
        {
            record.setObject(NSString(string: ""), forKey: "recordName")
            self.database.saveRecord(record) {_ in}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just do

```
record["user2reference"] = nil
```

After fetching the record from CloudKit